# SSH Client Session in C#

Tags: c#, ssh

I am trying to use SshNet (Renci) to create a ssh client session in my C# application. I cannot seem to understand how to get it to work. Essentially, I can get the connection to the server, but when I try to submit commands, I am not getting anything returned from the server. I am using SshClient and SshShell to perform the communication. What am I doing wrong?

```
ssh.Connect();

var input = new MemoryStream();
var sr = new StreamWriter(input);
var output = Console.OpenStandardOutput();

IDictionary<Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes, uint> termkvp = new Dictionary<Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes, uint>();
termkvp.Add(Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes.ECHO, 53);

var shell = ssh.CreateShell(input, output, output, "xterm", 80, 24, 800, 600, termkvp, 1024);
shell.Stopped += delegate
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nDisconnected...");
};

shell.Start();

while (true)
{
    string command = Console.ReadLine();

    if (command == "exit") break;

    sr.WriteLine(command);
    sr.Flush();
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1);
}

shell.Stop();
```

Comment: curious about if you stepped through the code and if so can you determine and or report back as to where the code breakdown is happening..?

Comment: @MethodMan I have stepped through it. I am not sure how to see what the server is returning, so I am not sure where it's breaking.